# Updating a column

Tags: sql

I have a table with a status column (initially with `progress`). I need to update this column's value to `success`.

Is this query what I want?

```
Update "tablename" set status='success' where status='progress'
```

The reason I am asking is that both the update and the where condition are checking the same column.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That statement will change the value for each row where status was "progress" to "success". Is that really what you want?

Comment: My question is - Is it work?, because here i have used the status for modifying and also in where condition.

Answer (score 4):

That will work but it will modify **all** rows that have progress in that column.

I think you probably want to limit the update based on some other part of the record.

For example if it were the progress of installing a particular piece of software (say Ubuntu on machine number 7):

```
update tbl set status='success'
where status='progress'
and machine_id = 7
and software = 'Ubuntu'
```

From a conceptual point of view, it's gathering the list of records to change first (with the `where` clause), then applying the `update ... set` to all those records.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that is correct, identify the row/s you want to change and commit the information to the specirfifed columns:

```
Update MyTable set Allowed = 1 WHERE Allowed = 0 AND UserID = 123
```

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 2):

yes, that's correct, all rows where status = 'progress' will be updated

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine. That will update every row in the table that's "progress" to be "success" though, not only one. I'm not sure if that's what you want or not.